# How to deal with csv file whoese fields are enclosed by quote?

Tags: csv, csvsimple

I have a csv file whose fields contain text. As fields can contains newlines, they are enclosed by double quotes. Editing these file works well with my favourite spreadsheet (libreoffice). I want to render this file but I got the following issues:

- the quotes are rendered
- the new lines are ignored

I use csvsimple, but it may not be the best choice. Here is a simple working sample in 3 files:

data.csv:

```
"1st field", "numerical field", "string field"
"foo", 3, "bar"
"xizzy", 0, "lorem
ipsum"
"nothing", 1,"last string"
```

data_simple.csv:

```
1st field, numerical field, string field
foo, 3, bar
xizzy, 0, lorem ipsum
nothing, 1,last string
```

csvtest.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}
\csvautotabular{./data_simple.csv}
\csvautotabular{./data.csv}
\end{document}
```

the table corresponding to data_simple.csv is OK, the one corresponding to data.csv is not as I expected.

Comment: You can't have entries split across lines, sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TeX can be instructed to ignore a character, by assigning it the category code 9. This will not affect usages of `\"` in the file.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
"1st field", "numerical field", "string field"
"foo", 3, "bar"
"xizzy", 0, "lorem
ipsum"
"nothing", 1,"last string"
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}

\begingroup\catcode`"=9
\csvautotabular{\jobname.csv}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

I used `filecontents*` with `\jobname.csv` as name just for avoiding clobbering my files.

[image]

Note, however, that you can't have an entry straddling two lines. This is due to the fact that `cvssimple` reads the file line by line with TeX's method and there is no way for it to decide a line has not ended, with that markup.

Comment: I like your answer better.  I will delete mine.